# Can I send error messages after committing data to HttpServletResponse

Tags: java, http, servlets, response, mime

everyone.

If an error is occurred after committing a part of data to HttpServletResponse, 
can I send error messages or replace http status code?
I investigated some functions (sendError, sendStatus, etc.), but I wasn't able to find a solution.
It's usual, isn't it?

If so, servers need to store all data before sending a lot data.
I think that servers can never have enough memories.

p.s.
I must send a lot data such as video data. It's so big data, so I don't want to store a lot data before sending. Umm :-(

Comment: You're correct.   You must set the status and headers before sending response data.  If you properly separate out your concerns properly though (for example, you might do MVC pattern), you will know if there is an error that needs to be reported via http status before you start sending any response.

Comment: The HTTP status code is one of the first data items that is sent. Once it is sent you can't change it.

Comment: That said, `HttpServletResponse` *are* buffered.  If the buffer gets overrun, however - the server will just start sending data.

Comment: For years, I used an "imperative" style, doing essentially the same thing, compute some things, output them, compute some more, output.

The problem is if you have half of a page outputted and get an error you can't change the response easily.

It's generally easier IMHO to use a "functional" style where the entire response is computed into a String or StringBuffer, then the object is returned by your main function and output all at once.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to increase the buffer and reset it if error occurs. This could help you to "patch" your code. But with video-content it could be probably difficult.

You can experiment with the following code.

- http://localhost:8080/BufferedResponse?flash
- http://localhost:8080/BufferedResponse

The Servlet:

```
package testingThings;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/BufferedResponse")
public class BufferedResponse extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.getWriter().println("buffer size: " + response.getBufferSize());
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);

        String flash = request.getParameter("flash");
        if (flash != null) {
            response.flushBuffer();
        }

        if (response.isCommitted()) {
            response.getWriter().println("buffer was commited.");
            response.getWriter().println("it is too late change the response");
        }
        else {
            response.resetBuffer();
            response.getWriter().println("buffer reseted.");
            response.getWriter().println("response and status code were changed");
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_FOUND);
        }
    }

}
```

Or like others suggested, separate the logic from the view.

At least you can process the data, write "log" (as preparation for response). If everything was ok and no error occurs, write the "log" in the response.